# Visual Studio Doesn’t Show New Properties after Recompiling Reference DLL

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Ugh that title is major title gore.

I have  visual studio 2015 community. I added Fleck via nuget to make a websocket server.

I decided to add some new properties to a class called Connectioninfo. So I uninstall Fleck from my project.

I download the source from git, modified it, built the DLL then added a reference to that DLL in my websockets server.

I know that it works because I ran the server with the modified dll.

However I can’t access the new properties I made,  visual studio processes an error when I try and force it.

I made a brand new project and added the same DLL and I see my new properties. So can anyone tell me why my original web sockets server project is not showing my modifications?

I typed this on my phone so please excuse typos.

Comment: A common mistake would be to have forgotten to add the "public" access modifier to your properties.

Comment: I can post the code later but I definitely made the properties public. Like I said, if I start a new project I see them, it’s like it’s some sort of caching issue or something strange like that.